# Is it possible to insert a value from one table to another on the basis of value using trigger?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I've a table named employee. 
I've two other tables named hrm, accounting.
I want to insert the employee into hrm and accounting table according to their departments.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
employee_id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
employee_first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_department VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));
```

according to the employee_department, I want to insert that employee to that particular table.

```
CREATE TABLE hrm (
employee_id INT(4),
employee_designation VARCHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
    REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE accounting (
employee_id INT(4),
employee_designation VARCHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
    REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

if employee_department is hrm, I want that employee to get inserted into hrm table, how can i do it through mysql trigger or stored procedure?

Comment: The trigger should be `AFTER INSERT` when new employees is inserted? `AFTER UPDATE` if employees departments is update? `AFTER DELETE` when employees is deleted?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, but initially I'm looking forward to this insertion if possible

Comment: Hard to tell if this question is about triggers/procedures or flow control statements

Comment: @P.Salmon this question was bout flow control inside trigger/procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `employees_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `employees` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF NEW.employee_department = 'hrm' THEN
      INSERT INTO hrm 
        (employee_id, employee_designation) 
      VALUES
        (NEW.employee_id, /*whatever you add here*/);
  END IF;

END
```

I will explain some key point :

- In an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, you can get the inserted valued using `NEW`. So here : `NEW.employee_department` is equal to the inserted `employee_department` value of the new employee, same for `NEW.employee_id` (for `AFTER DELETE` trigger you can use `OLD` and for `AFTER UPDATE` you have `NEW` for the updated value and `OLD` for the value before the update)
- In a MySQL trigger, you can add condition : here I check if the new `employee_department` of the new employee is equal to "hrm" : if YES THEN do an insert in your hrm table, ELSE the trigger do nothing
- If you want to do the same for "accounting", the logic will be the same

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck on that NEW. Your explanation has given a concrete idea bout it.

Comment: Glad to helped you :)